# Remote IP based SSL in Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In plain nginx, I can use the [nginx geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) to set a variable based on the remote address. I can use this variable in the ssl path to choose a different SSL certificate and key for different remote networks accessing the server. This is necessary because the different network environments have different CAs.

How can I reproduce this behavior in a Kubernetes nginx ingress? or even Istio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the generated config both for the base and for each Ingress. I'm not familiar with the config you are describing but some mix of the various *-snippet configmap options (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-snippet) or a custom template (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/)

Comment: The Configmap options do not help, I could probably build a custom template. However, the geo variable assignment is global and not on a per-server basis. Doesn't the ingress instantiate one full template-based config for each ingress resource? Also, doesn't the manual ssl config interfere with the ingress resource tls specification?

Comment: You would probably need some of both, main-snippet to initialize global stuff and then a custom template for the per-ingress bits. That would include changing the default TLS cert handling, since that's all in the template :)